# cast File[] into String[] for put it inside arrayadapter

Tags: android, file, casting, android-arrayadapter

I need to fill an arrayadapter with the name of files.
i've call this function to retrieve the list of files inside the directory:

```
File dir_path = getApplicationContext().getDir(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE);
File[] children = dir_path.listFiles();
```

now i need to take all filename inside children array and put it inside the array adapter. I need to cast element by element, or there's another way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like the following. [getName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29) will give you the name of the file that File object is associated with, and the loop will populate a String array with the names.

```
String names = new String[children.length];
for(int i=0;i<children.length;i++) {
    names[i] = children[i].getName();
}
```

Then simply pass the `names` array to your ArrayAdapter.